# Use an external Bearer Token in order to execute a REST API

Tags: spring-boot, bearer-token, findall

I have a Bearer Token what do I have to do to be able to use it inside a findAll type REST API in Spring Boot.
I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
@GetMapping ("/ all")
public List <MMModel> findAll (@RequestHeader (name = "Authorization") String token);
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your token is a JWT token, which is most likely the case, you can import spring-boot-starter-security, which contains all the necessary tools for authentication.

Maven

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Gradle

```
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
```

Then your `GetMapping` would like like

```
 @GetMapping ("/ all")
 public List <MMModel> findAll (@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt token)
```

Comment: OK, but I have a token like this: (eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJpTXN5NjVaTGpRTFQ1OS1Zb....) How Can I use it in the swagger with your modification ??? Because in the swagger i see different sections: issuerUri, jwkSetUri, jwsAlgorithm, publicKeyLocation.URI.absolute ecc...

Comment: I don't know about Swagger. What you have is the encoded token. Just pass the encoded token in the Authorization header, and @AuthenticationPrincipal will decode it for you. You will get a Jwt object containing all the tokens info.